# Find Min/Max from 1 textbox

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to find the Min/Max value of a textbox that has 1 variable and display it to the user, so the variable changes everytime the button is clicked. How would I find the maximum value of something that is constantly changing? The trick is that I can **NOT** use if statements or case statements. I'm totally at a loss here.

Comment: Why can't you use if or case?

Comment: It is better to do it by your self , ask us if there are errors for example

Comment: For Math.Max/Math.Min you need two values. One value is the one currently inputted in the textBox and the other one has to be the maximum/minimum sofar (which you have to store somewhere, for example, in a global variable). In any case, SO is not the place to ask how to solve your assignments; the whole point of the assigment is you doing it by your own.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the things that limit you.

- One variable
- no `if`/`case` statements

The lesson seems to revolve around using `Math.Max()`.

`Math.Max()`, as we can see on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs0a3045.aspx) returns

> the larger of two 32-bit signed integers.

The one variable we are going to use needs to exist outside of the button's `click` event. So, just make it a class variable.

This variable will essentially store the largest value. `Math.Max()` returns the largest of two values... see what I am getting at here? You can pass the current largest variable as a parameter to `Math.Max()` without any issues.

---

#### Example:

```
Dim max As Integer

max = Math.Max(1, 100)
'max would be 100
max = Math.Max(max, 10)
'max would be 100
max = Math.Max(max, 1000)
'max would be 1000
```

Comment: I've been stuck on this for hours... How can I store the largest number without using an if statement?

Comment: I will add a simple example, that I hope will explain it... without giving too much away.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks

Comment: @CoreyWilliams That's great. Hopefully my answer helped you a little bit. Here's some unsolicited advice: I think you are more clever than you give yourself credit. Be careful of coming to StackOverflow for help too easily. Sometimes people will be helpful, sometimes they will just give you the answer. Your professor/Teacher will (hopefully) always act in the interest of what is best for your education, so be sure to ask them questions if you can.